# Запретить сворачивание окна вместе с приложением

Tags: delphi

Одно из окон приложения не должно сворачиваться при сворачивании главной формы. Использую такое решение:

```
procedure TForm2.createParams(var params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited createParams(params);
  with params do begin
    exStyle := (exStyle or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
    wndParent := getDesktopWindow();
  end;
end;
```

Не работает, форма сворачивается и возвращаться вместе с главной уже не хочет. Без `exStyle := (exStyle or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);` работает, но в панели задач появляется дополнительный значок. Как можно было бы решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Может, не до конца понял все варианты ситуации, но я бы сделал так:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    <...>
  private
    procedure WMSysCommand(var Msg: TWMSysCommand);message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
    <...>
  protected
    <...>
  public
    <...>
  end;

procedure TForm1.WMSysCommand(var Msg: TWMSysCommand);
begin
   if Msg.CmdType = SC_MINIMIZE then
     begin
      // в простейшем варианте, когда есть только 2 формы           
       Form1.WindowState:=wsMinimized; 
      // когда форм много, обращайтесь к Screen.Forms и минимизируйте все, кроме нужной

     end
   else inherited;
end;
```